# How to get the indices for randomly selected rows in a list (Python)

Tags: python, search, random, machine-learning, indices

Okay, I don't know if I phrased it badly or something, but I can't seem to find anything similar here for my problem.

So I have a 2D list, each row representing a case and each column representing a feature (for machine learning). In addition, I have a separated list (column) as labels.

I want to randomly select the rows from the 2D list to train a classifier while using the rest to test for accuracy. Thus I want to be able to know all the indices of rows I used for training to avoid repeats.

I think there are 2 parts of the question:
1) how to randomly select
2) how to get indices

again I have no idea why I can't find good info here by searching (maybe I just suck)

Sorry I'm still new to the community so I might have made a lot of format mistake. If you have any suggestion, please let me know.

Here's the part of code I'm using to get the 2D list

```
#273 = number of cases
feature_list=[[0]*len(mega_list)]*273
#create counters to use for index later
link_count=0
feature_count=0
#print len(mega_list)
for link in url_list[:-1]:

    #setup the url
    samp_url='http://www.mtsamples.com'+link
    samp_url = "%20".join( samp_url.split() )

    #soup it for keywords
    samp_soup=BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(samp_url).read())
    keywords=samp_soup.find('meta')['content']
    keywords=keywords.split(',')

    for keys in keywords:
        #print 'megalist: '+ str(mega_list.index(keys))
        if keys in mega_list:
            feature_list[link_count][mega_list.index(keys)]=1
```

mega_list: a list with all keywords

feature_list: the 2D list, with any word in mega_list, that specific cell is set to 1, otherwise 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the data in a pandas data frame instead of a 2D list. If I understand your data right you could do that like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(feature_list, columns = mega_list)
```

I don't see any mention of a dependent variable, but I'm assuming you have one because you mentioned a classifier algorithm. If your dependent variable is called "Y" and is in a list format with indices that align with your features,  then this code will work for you:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
    df, Y, test_size=0.8, random_state=0)
```

Comment: hey! Yes I do have a dependent variable, just not mentioned in the code I provided. I think I'll give this algo a try! Will report back haha. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, after taking a closer look, this might not be needed. I'm using Naive Bayes for Multi Nominal fit, it seems like


{clf = MultinomialNB()
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)}


will do the job (it's the example from the website). I'm not quite sure though, and I feel this thread is starting to stray away from the original topic lol

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the problem, you have a list and you want to sample the list and save the indices for future use.
See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

you could do a random.sample(xrange(sizeoflist),sizeofsample) which will return the indices of your sample. You can then use that sample for training and skip over them (or get fancy and do a Set difference) for validation.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, this solves the problem. Though now more problems surface..... ANOTHER THREAD I GO!